# Implementing Gesture recognition even while focus is on other Activities

Tags: android, gestures

I am trying to make an app that recognizes gestures even while my app is not focused.

I would like it to be a permanently running service.

Can you point me in the right direction. I can research it myself I just don't know what terms to search. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb and say that I do not believe this is possible. Gestures are recognized by the UI through Views as far as I know... so a background Service could never respond to touch/gesture events.

Comment: I really just need to have a listener that is always watching a portion of the screen for certain gestures. Or can I make a translucent View Always on top that lets everything else work right through it?

Comment: Unless someone says otherwise... I'm pretty confident nothing like this is possible.